# Snippet Designer/Editor for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, editor, code-snippets, vsx

What Editors/Designers for creating Visual Studio 2010 Snippets are there?

I would like to be able to put in different replacements (ie spots where the text should be replaced).  A low incidence of blocking bugs is also nice.

So far the only one I have seen is [Snippet Editor 2.1](http://snippeteditor.codeplex.com/).  I am going to dig into it and see how it works, but I did not want to spend too much time on that app if there is a better one out there.

Answer (score 3):

I like [Snippet Designer by Matt Manela](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/B08B0375-139E-41D7-AF9B-FAEE50F68392) and chose to use it in my Extending Visual Studio course. I like the Snippet Explorer and searching snippets as well as the designer view to help you edit them, including replacements. It also gives you a nice Export as Snippet context menu item. And the code is on CodePlex if you would like to learn how it's done.

Comment: The Export as Snippet  functionality doesn't work in web apps, does it?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com) and search for "snippet" in the "Find" box.  You should find several options (e.g. [Snippet Designer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/B08B0375-139E-41D7-AF9B-FAEE50F68392), [Snipper](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/3439b095-03f5-4db7-ae3f-ba2cbe09c876), etc.).  I haven't used any of these so I can't attest to how good they may be but at least it's a start.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper (not free) has it's own snippet system which is really great. I'm adding this answer because I was searching for something not realising I already had something installed (Resharper)